# Add Table in footer in every pages of PDF

Tags: spfx, pdf, react-webpart

I created a function which adds table in the footer as shown in the image. But if I add more data in any cell it overflows on the other cell. I want the height of a row adjust according to the sentence and content must use another line if it exceeds the cell's width. can anyone tell me how can I do this.

Is there any other option for doing this?

```
async function addHeaderAndFooterToPDF() {

    const fileUrl ='';

    const response = await fetch(fileUrl);
    const pdfBytes = await response.arrayBuffer();

    // Load the PDF with pdf-lib
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
    const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();


    // Create a new page for the footer content
    const footerContent = pdfDoc.getPages()[0];

    // Define the table content
    const tableContent = [
        ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3'],
        ['Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3'],
        ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'],
        ['Info 1', 'Info 2', 'Info 3'],
    ];

    const cellWidth = 100;
    const cellHeight = 20;
    const startX = 50;
    const startY = 50;
    const borderWidth = 1; // Border width in points

    // Draw the table content onto the existing footer page
    for (let row = 0; row < tableContent.length; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < tableContent[row].length; col++) {
            const cellText = tableContent[row][col];
            const x = startX + col * cellWidth;
            const y = startY - row * cellHeight;

            // Draw cell background
            footerContent.drawRectangle({
                x,
                y,
                width: cellWidth,
                height: cellHeight,
                borderWidth: borderWidth,
                borderColor: rgb(0, 0, 0), 
               
            });

            // Draw cell text
            footerContent.drawText(cellText, {
                x: x + borderWidth,
                y: y - borderWidth - 10, // Adjust for text alignment
                font: await pdfDoc.embedFont('Helvetica'),
                size: 12,
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0), 
            });
        }

        // Draw horizontal line between rows
        const lineY = startY - (row + 1) * cellHeight;
        footerContent.drawLine({
            start: { x: startX, y: lineY },
            end: { x: startX + cellWidth * tableContent[0].length, y: lineY },
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0), // Line color in RGB format [R, G, B]
            thickness: borderWidth,
        });
    }

    // Draw vertical lines between columns
    for (let col = 0; col <= tableContent[0].length; col++) {
        const lineX = startX + col * cellWidth;
        footerContent.drawLine({
            start: { x: lineX, y: startY },
            end: { x: lineX, y: startY - cellHeight * tableContent.length },
            // color: rgb(0, 0, 0), // Line color in RGB format [R, G, B]
            thickness: borderWidth,
        });
    }
  
    // Serialize the modified PDF
    const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

    // Create a Blob from the modified PDF bytes
    const modifiedPdfBlob = new Blob([modifiedPdfBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    // Optionally, you can download the modified PDF
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(modifiedPdfBlob);
    downloadLink.download = 'PageNO_Added_Published.pdf';
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

[image]